# Error while installing SUMO in M1 Pro MacBook(Ventura)

Tags: macos, homebrew, sumo

I was installing SUMO at my MacBook by home-brew reading the install documentation but there is an error while installing it. Please help me.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4woCE.png)

I've reinstalled home-brew and did `brew update` and `brew upgrade` but it didn't fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The name of the bottle on github has changed now, please try again.

older answer:

I am not sure why but the file is named `sumo--1.16.0.arm64_ventura.bottle.tar.gz`. Please note the double dash in the filename after sumo.